# VS Code Dark+ Theme not working on Jupyter Notebook. Functions and Modules not colored. Looking for Solution

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook

I have attached an image to show how the coloration is different between the original python code and the Jupyter Notebook. On the Left is the original python code with the correct coloration of the theme. On the right is the Python Code in a Jupyter Notebook. How do I get the coloration of the left to work on right?

[Image of Issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Swra.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Jupyter notebook lacks the ability of `Semantic Token Colorization`:

The theme of `Dark+` which you are using (**Developer: Inspect Editor Tokens and Scopes**):

[image]

[image]

The theme of `SynthWave '84`:

[image]

[image]

So, you can try to switch to another theme that can work better than the default one.

Comment: Egads! Thank you for the assistance in my time of aid!!!!